# How to find a particular solution of a differential equation with a fractional function of x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am finding $y$ that satisfies
$$y^{(4)}-81y = \frac{12}{x^5}-\frac{40.5}{x}.$$

First, we can easily find $y_h$ as follows:

1. The characteristic function can be derived as $\lambda^4 - 81$=0.
2. From the characteristic function, we have $\lambda = \pm3$ or $\lambda = \pm i3$.
3. Hence, we have $$y_h = c_1 e^{3x} + c_2 e^{-3x} + c_3 \cos(3x) + c_4 \sin(3x).$$

Next, if the RHS has the form of $C_1 x^\alpha + C_2 x^\beta$ for any real numbers of $C_1$ and $C_2$, we can assume $y_p$ has the form as follows: $$y_p = \sum_{j=0}^\alpha c_{1,j} x^j + \sum_{k=0}^\beta c_{2,k} x^k,$$ where $c_{1,0}, c_{1,1}, \ldots, c_{1,\alpha}, c_{2,0}, c_{2,1}, \ldots, c_{2,\beta}$ are all arbitrary numbers.

**However, I do not know how to assume a form of $y_p$ for a fractional function of x.** Can someone solve the problem above?

Comment: $\lambda^4 - 81\lambda$ has the solution $\lambda =0$ but not $\lambda=\pm 3$

Comment: Also, the characteristic eq should be $\lambda^2-81 = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make as an ansatz $$y_p = \frac{c}{x}.$$
This will give you a simple particular solution (solving for $c$).

Comment: Is there a rule for determining ansatz? For example, if the RHS is $\frac{a_1}{x^{c_1}}+\frac{a_2}{x^{c_2}}+\frac{a_3}{x^{c_3}}+\cdots$, then is it fine if I set $y_p = c/{x^{\min_j c_j}}$, where $c_k\in\mathbb{N}, \forall k$?

Comment: I'm not sure.  But probably similar to undetermined coeffs method for polynomials.